# Related router links is not working for named router outlets for Angular 16

Tags: angular

I faced with issue the related links which work for Angular 15 is not working for Angular 16.

they looks like :
`<a routerLink="./secret"> ./secret works in Angular 15</a>`

the route:

```
const sandboxRouting=[
  {
    path: '',
    component: SandBoxComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: "full" as any,
        component: DrawerComponent,
        outlet: 'sand'
      },{
        path: 'secret',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: SecretComponent,
            outlet: 'sand'
          }]
      },

  ]}
];
```

I expected these links will work (as it described in the doc)

```
<a routerLink="../secret"> ../secret </a><br>
<a [routerLink]="['..','secret']">['..','secret']</a><br>
```

but they do not.

there is [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e7efc6?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&title=Angular%20Starter) with example of app. please follow by "go there".
(the structure of the app reflect my real application)